# not able to append same child to two div elements created by by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
while(i < check){
    randImage = retImgNodes();  //return image nodes
    div1.appendChild(randImage);  //append to div1
    console.log("appended div1");
    randImage2 = randImage;       //variable name is not a problem
    div2.appendChild(randImage2);
    console.log("appended div2");
    i++ ;
    //txt = document.createTextNode("hi")
    //div2.appendChild(txt);
}
theBody.appendChild(div1);
theBody.appendChild(div2);
```

Comment: you will need to clone that div before appending again.

Comment: Did you read any [`.appendChild()` doco](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)? That method will *move* an existing element, not copy it...

Comment: Voted for close - unclear what you're asking. Please read [ask] and [answer] and so improve your post quality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By design, you are not able to place a single element in more than one location in the DOM. If you attempt to do so, the element will be moved from its current location to the location where you are inserting it.

If you desire, you can create a duplicate of a node by using [`cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode). You can then insert that duplicate into the DOM at a different location.

You might want to read the documentation for [documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document), [nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node), and [elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element).

For instance the documentation for [`appendChild()` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) says (emphasis mine):

> The Node.appendChild() method adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node. **If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new position** (there is no requirement to remove the node from its parent node before appending it to some other node).
>
> **This means that a node can't be in two points of the document simultaneously. So if the node already has a parent, the node is first removed, then appended at the new position.** The [Node.cloneNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) can be used to make a copy of the node before appending it under the new parent. Note that the copies made with cloneNode will not be automatically kept in sync.

Comment: Thank you so much!! it solved my problem!