# How to append elements to all items in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, append

I'm trying to add a delete button to all items with a specific class in a menu but when I try to loop through the array of classes and append the button it can only be added to one of the items, anyone know how I can fix it?

```
let menuItems = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item');
let deleteButton = document.getElementById('deleteButton');

for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
  menuItems[i].append(deleteButton);
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [not able to append same child to two div elements created by by javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38584486/not-able-to-append-same-child-to-two-div-elements-created-by-by-javascript)

Comment: you need to create a new element for each item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clone that element, and please don't use an ID, otherwise you'll end up having duplicated IDs.

```js
const ELS_menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item');
const EL_deleteButton = document.querySelector('#deleteButton');

ELS_menuItems.forEach(EL_item => EL_item.append(EL_deleteButton.cloneNode(true)));  
// Be advised that you'll end up having duplicated IDs in your DOM now
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll